# Hashmap as param for a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, hashmap

I have a fragment with an ExpandableList which content is provided by a `HashMap<String,List<String>>`. This `HashMap<String,List<String>>` is filled in Fragment's Activity and i need to pass it to the fragment.

To do it, i was planning to do a Fragment transaction but i found the problem:

In the method "newInstance" of the fragment, when setting arguments to the Bundle, there is no method to put a HashMap.

Ex:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(ARG_PARAM1,index); //method .putHashmap doesn't exist.
```

So, how can i pass my hashmap in bundle to the Fragment? Please provide an solution for this one.Thanks in advance

Comment: Soo, your activity knows the Fragment it is displaying right? Why don't you  just pass it through a method? Or your activity implements an interface to retrieve the map, which the fragment can call.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To pass HashMap do this

```
MyFragment fr = new MyFragment(); // Replace with your Fragment class
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("hashmap",mMap);
fr.setArguments(bundle);
```

To retrieve do this

```
HashMap<String,List<String>> mMap = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
Bundle b = this.getArguments();
if(b.getSerializable("hashmap") != null)
   mMap = (HashMap<String,List<String>>)b.getSerializable("hashmap");
```

Comment: warning unchecked cast

Comment: + uniqueNt You can safely ignore this warning, since you defined type of map your own. (put this line above warning line: `// noinspection unchecked`)

Comment: Great answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable(ARG_PARAM1, hereGoesYourHashMap);
```

as according to the docs:

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html

[HashMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) is [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html)